# Processing result from linux command

Tags: bash

I am trying to write program which will monitor number of operations on hard disk.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; 
do
    operations=$(iostat -dx /dev/mapper/kaliMichu--vg-home)
    echo "$operations"
    sleep 5
done
```

So I used iostat for that. 
Actually I am only interested in some parameters for example w/s.
How can I catch it's value into variable e.g WS=$w/s_value

Comment: try `operations=$(iostat -dx /dev/mapper/kaliMichu--vg-home|awk 'NR>3{print $5}')`  where `5` is the column number of the result of `w/s`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Works like a charm. If you post this as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; 
do
    operations=$(iostat -dx /dev/mapper/kaliMichu--vg-home|awk 'NR>3{print $5}')
    echo "$operations"
    sleep 5
done
```

Here, `awk` is filterning the desired column for you.

Comment: What if I potencially want to get two parameters? It is possible to call iostat one time and make two variables with different values?

Comment: It's possible using eval or declare  command . However it's wise to run command twice for two different columns.

Comment: Why is it wise?

Comment: Because eval is dependent on the input supplied to it and it may break easily.i will provide you that command too in few mins. Traveling now.but I would restrict my self fro using eval.

Comment: `declare $(iostat -dx /dev/sda7 |awk 'NR>3&&NF{print "ws="$5;print "rs="$4}')` then `echo $ws` and `echo $rs`  . you have been warned. PS: Change the device to yours.